# SublimeREPL does not run

Tags: python, keyboard, sublimetext, key-bindings

I used SublimeREPL happily, then I wanted "Open with SubilimeText" option to be on right-click. So I installed Sublime Text (without removing) with "Add to explorer context menu" checked. And now when I press F7 SublimeREPL does nothing.

The only way it runs Python files is

> Tools > SublimeREPL > Python > RUN Current File

I tried to remove REPL.build-system, re-installing package. Doesn't help.
How can I fix it?

Comment: This has been reported a lot over at the forums, but at the moment nobody is sure what exactly is going on and why this particular package seems to be (at least partially) broken in Sublime Text 3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the fix faster than you guys but thanks anyways :). 
If anybody have the same problem this may help:

> Open **Sublime Text** > Go to **Preferences** > **Key Bindings**

In "Key Bindings - User" tab paste the following code (*Note: I set key "F7", but any other free key can be set*):

```
[
{
    "keys": ["f7"],
    "command": "repl_open",
    "args": {
                "cmd": ["python", "-u", "-i", "$file_basename"],
                "cwd": "$file_path",
                "encoding": "utf8",
                "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"},
                "external_id": "python",
                "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                "type": "subprocess"
            }
}]
```